שמך vocalization before Shema
In Shakharit, the last word of אהבת עולם before the Bracha, is ״שמך״. In all the Siddurim I usually use, that word is vocalized as שִמְךָ. However, I have often heard people read it as שְמֶךָ.
As far as I know, the latter is grammatically correct since it’s the pausal form, which is appropriate for the last word of a clause.
I mostly use אור השלום, עבודת ה׳, עת רצון, and קול שמחה (all אדות המזרח)ץ
So do the siddurim I use have a typo? Or am I wrong, and they’re correct? Or is it a matter of Nusach, with neither one being incorrect? Something else? Why?

Sefaria has שִׁמְךָ for Edot Hamizrach and שְׁמֶךָ for Nusach Sfard.

It might help to tell us what siddur you're looking at. Note also that the use of pausal forms in prayer is an old makhloket.

@JMS Interesting. That adds the question of which is correct, if that is applicable.

@magicker72 I’m using אור השלום, עבודת ה׳, and עת רצון. (I’ve seen the first one in different formats and with different names, and siddurim clearly based on it with some minor additions).

@magicker72 is the debate based on Mishnaic vs Biblical Hebrew, or something else?

Is it really the last word in a "verse"? The text only ends a few words later ...בעמו ישראל באהבה

@QwertyCTRL. Yes it's part of that discussion.

@DoubleAA I assumed it ended a sentence/verse (what are those called in Tephillah? Pessukim?), although I might be wrong. Still, it’s definitely a major break, so the pausal form is still appropriate.

@QwertyCTRL Is it definitely a major break? It seems clearly to not be a break at all since we purposefully use the last text to connect to the closing (מעין החתימה סמוך לחתימה). (A larger point here is even if you hold we should overlay biblical hebrew rules on all texts, you're still left with the problem of defining where exactly a stop is as even in Tanach it's not always super obvious.)

@DoubleAA The ending of Modim with סלה could indicate that it's a break
